# Administrator RUNAS feature on iisreset in command line

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, runas

While trying to run iisreset from CMD.exe on a Windows 7 64 bit, I got to know the difference of run as admin or not.

My question: As the local admin - is the difference on the CMD is the ONLY difference?  or is it possible that other services/tools are behaving differently?

If there IS a difference, anything else I can do to cancel that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the UAC Elevation, so yes - UAC affects basically all programs, but not all programs requires Elevation.
Anyhow, If you'd like to disable this feature then there are several options [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-and-turn-off-uac-in-windows-7/).